# Detect if buttons are inside drawn rect box

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a canvas with a rectangle box for marquee selecting and my uniformgrid which contains my buttons that are dynamically produced.

The marquee selection tool is now working i.e. i can see it being drawn over the uniform grid and i've got the mousedown position and mouseup position per the example code here:

[Click and drag selection box in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838163/click-and-drag-selection-box-in-wpf)

My XAML is this:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Width="800" Height="400">
    <Rectangle x:Name="selectionBox" Visibility="Collapsed" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeDashArray="2,1"/>
    <UniformGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="uniformGrid" Grid.Row="1" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=mainGrid}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=mainGrid}"
Rows="{Binding RowCount}"
Columns="{Binding ColumnCount}" MouseDown="UniformGrid_MouseDown" MouseUp="UniformGrid_MouseUp" MouseMove="UniformGrid_MouseMove" Background="Transparent">
    </UniformGrid>
    <Canvas Name="buttonCanvas">
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Thing is, i'm not sure how to check if my buttons (which are children of the UniformGrid) are contained/partially contained in this rect.

Comment: If the `UniformGrid` is inside of the `Rectangle`, and the grid contains the buttons, wouldn't the buttons automatically all be contained in the `Rectangle` anyway?

Comment: Oh never mind the grid is not in the rectangle. The formatting threw me off.

Comment: You can get all the controls inside of a control by using `Control.Childred` property, and you can use `uniformGrid.Children.OfType<Button>()` to get all the buttons inside your grid. Then you can obtain the coordinates of the rectangle, as well as the coordinates of the buttons, and it's a matter of comparing after that.

Comment: Hey Sach. I've got the mousedown position coordinates and the mouseup position coordinates. I'm sure I can also get the coordinates of the buttons somehow but I'm not sure how this would be in code. If you look at the link in my question, the MouseUp event that is included in the popular answer for that question is where I'm stuck at in terms of what to write. Could you help with an example?

Comment: Be aware that by putting the UniformGrid into the Canvas you'll loose your layout, if you ever intend to have it resizable.

Comment: Not sure how else to do it Clemens

Comment: On top of the UniformGrid, in a common parent Panel, e.g. a Grid. Just as shown in the answer to your previous question. However, the other way round, the Canvas over the UniformGrid, not under it.

Comment: Hey @Clemens, I've edited my answer - does the XAML look any better?

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. Now there are two Canvases, *both* under the UniformGrid.

Comment: I thought they were above the uniformgrid... :\ *sighs*

Comment: I've changed it again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197835/discussion-between-slickchick2-and-clemens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expansion to the solution you've linked.

Following is a method that will decided a given button is inside the given `MouseUp` and `MouseDown` position. In that example, there's a member variable called `mouseDownPos`, and a local variable called `mouseUpPos`, which registers each of those. So, inside the `Grid_MouseUp` event handler, I'd add the following code to grab all the `Button` controls in your `Canvas`, iterate each of them and pass them to a method to see if it's inside the said area.

```
private void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Release the mouse capture and stop tracking it.
    mouseDown = false;
    theGrid.ReleaseMouseCapture();

    // Hide the drag selection box.
    selectionBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    Point mouseUpPos = e.GetPosition(theGrid);

    // TODO: 
    //
    // The mouse has been released, check to see if any of the items 
    // in the other canvas are contained within mouseDownPos and 
    // mouseUpPos, for any that are, select them!
    //
    var buttons = canvasButtons.Children.OfType<System.Windows.Controls.Button>();

    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        var isInSelection = IsInsideSelection(mouseDownPos, mouseUpPos, button);
    }
}
```

The `IsInsideSelection()` is a function that I wrote, which asks for the mouse up and down positions of the rectangle, and for the `Button` control.

```
private bool IsInsideSelection(Point mouseDown, Point mouseUp, System.Windows.Controls.Button button)
{
    // This grabs the coordinates of the button, relative to the main window. 
    // If you would like it relative to something else, like your canvas or the grid, you'd have to pass appropriate control to the `TransformToAncestor()` function.
    var buttonPos = button.TransformToAncestor(mainWin).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

    // Bottom right corner coordinates of the button control.
    var btnBottomRight = new Point(buttonPos.X + button.Width, buttonPos.Y + button.Height);

    // If button X and Y (which is the top left corner of the button) 
    // are outside the mouse down position, it's not inside the rectangle 
    if (buttonPos.X < mouseDown.X || buttonPos.Y < mouseDown.Y)
        return false;

    // If X and Y of button bottom right corner is outside mouse up coordinates,
    // then the control is again outside the rectangle
    if (btnBottomRight.X > mouseUp.X || btnBottomRight.Y > mouseUp.Y)
        return false;

    // Everything else, control is inside
    return true;
}
```

### NOTE:

- This grabs the coordinates of the button, relative to the main window. If you would like it relative to something else, like your canvas or the grid, you'd have to pass appropriate control to the `TransformToAncestor()` function.

### EDIT

The above function only works if the rectangle was drawn left-to-right. To handle the right-to-left scenario, you can switch the mouse up and down positions, like so:

```
private bool IsInsideSelection(Point mouseDown, Point mouseUp, System.Windows.Controls.Button button)
{
    if (mouseUp.X < mouseDown.X)
    {
        var temp = mouseUp;
        mouseUp = mouseDown;
        mouseDown = temp;
    }

    var buttonPos = button.TransformToAncestor(mainWin).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    var btnBottomRight = new Point(buttonPos.X + button.Width, buttonPos.Y + button.Height);

    if (buttonPos.X < mouseDown.X || buttonPos.Y < mouseDown.Y)
        return false;

    if (btnBottomRight.X > mouseUp.X || btnBottomRight.Y > mouseUp.Y)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

### EDIT 2:

Following is the `XAML` of my test app, and I'm using a `UniformGrid` to hold controls here. Note that when retrieving buttons, you must use the name of the `UniformGrid` to do so, in this case, 'unfGrid`.

```
<Window ...
        Name="mainWin"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">
    <Grid x:Name="theGrid"
          MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"
          MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp"
          MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove"
          Background="Transparent">
        <UniformGrid Name="unfGrid" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Name="Btn1" Content="Button1" Grid.Row="0"
                        Width="100" Height="24"/>
            <Button Name="Btn2" Content="Button2" Grid.Row="1"
                        Width="100" Height="24"/>
            <Button Name="Btn3" Content="Button3" Grid.Row="2"
                        Width="100" Height="24"/>
            <!-- This canvas contains elements that are to be selected -->
        </UniformGrid>

        <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
            <!-- This canvas is overlaid over the previous canvas and is used to 
            place the rectangle that implements the drag selection box. -->
            <Rectangle
                x:Name="selectionBox"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Stroke="Black"
                StrokeThickness="1"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hey Sach, the line `  var buttons = canvasButtons.Children.OfType<System.Windows.Controls.Button>();` is returning nothing. This is based on the XAML I have in my original post. I'm adding buttons to the uniformGrid like uniformGrid.Children.Add. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'canvasButtons' is the name I used for the canvas in my test code. In your case you must use the name of the canvas you're adding the buttons to, whatever that may be. Instead of simply copy pasting code, try to understand. I've already explained what the code does; you add buttons to a canvas, then in code behind, using the canvas name you get hold of those same buttons and evaluate their locations.

Comment: I understood the code and I said it was returning nothing, not that it wasn't compiling. I changed it to suit my canvas button name but I'm not adding to the canvas, i'm adding to the uniform grid because this is what I want - i don't want to be adding buttons to the canvas - only to the uniform grid. That's why I'm trying to understand if I can pull the buttons from the uniform grid instead of the canvas

Comment: Then simply add buttons to a `UniformGrid` instead of a canvas, and use the name of that grid to retrieve buttons. I just replaced the `Canvas` with a `UniformGrid` in my code, and it works just fine. I'll edit my answer and post my `XAML`.